# HoloLens + OpenCV for identifying real world Objects

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a scenario using HoloLens to identify real world objects.

**Scenario**

For example identifying  'N' different types of bottles whose dimensions are not known in prior. Each bottle may have different Height / Width . So I need to detect these bottles by gazing it through HoloLens and draw rectangle on it and give unique labels for each GameObject created. So that when I gaze these bottles the second time with the unique dimensions stored I would retrieve the mapped unique labels and show it to the user. Is this even possible ? And these bottles comes only in cylindrical shape placed horizontally on a conveyer belt.

**What I have tried so far**

Integrated Vuforia SDK for HoloLens. Uploaded 3D model of one bottle object in the Vuforia target manager.HoloLens was able to detect a bottle but I couldn't find a way to differentiate between many different bottles because of the varying dimensions.

**I need Help in**

Due to the fact that all bottles are cylindrical shaped except for varying height and width, is there way to detect the dimensions of these cylinders using OpenCV? So that I could create a rectangular box GameObject over it and map the unique label

**PS:** Am trying to implement a solution without markers(VuMark etc)

Comment: Have you considered labeling the bottles with some kind of symbol (I have used vumarks in the past https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/VuMark) to tell the difference between them? Or do you just want to recognize the bottle based on its witdth/height?

Comment: @DaanHuinink This solution has to be marker-less. Yes I have to recognise the bottle based on its width/height.